ASP.NET MVC datepicker doesn't show calendar
I'm trying to add datepicker, however when I try to use @html.TextboxFor, the calendar is not popping up. As for EditorFor to input="date" options, they show mm/dd/yyyy format when I need dd/mm/yyyy.
These are my scripts, I have jQuery UI combined nuget package installed:
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

When I try like this, the calendar is not showing.
@Html.LabelFor(x => x.Birthdate)
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Birthdate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Select birth date", id = "mydate" } })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Birthdate, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })

When I try this, a calendar is shown, but with mdy format, not dmy:
<input type="date" id="mydatepicker" name="Birthdate" class="form-control" placeholder="dd mm yy" autocomplete="off" />

And this is script:
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#mydatepicker").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd mm yy", // Set desired date format
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true
    });
});


input type="date" will use the built-in (generally ugly) basic date picker of whichever browser you are using.

$("#mydatepicker").datepicker({ needs to reference the ID= of a text input.  Given your @Html.TextBoxFor, this should be $("#mydate").datepicker({ or change your <input type="date" id="mydatepicker" to <input type="text" id="mydatepicker"

Hi,thank you!, I am using Google Chrome, I did update the Id,  @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Birthdate)
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Birthdate, "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", new { @type="date",@class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Select birth date" })
